# Should I call rollback in Sqlalchemy with autocommit=False?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm wondering if I should call rollback in SQLAlchemy after failed committing? If some errors will occur I want to continue saving objects. I don't care about transactional save.

```
engine = create_engine("db", convert_unicode=True, echo=False)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False))

for row in data:
    try:
        Session.add(row)
        Session.commit()
    except:
        # rollback ???

        # continue saving rest of the objects
        continue

Session.remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use Sqlachemy without autocommit, you need to maintain `Transactions` state manually by calling `session.commit()` and `session.rollback()`. There are [one](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html) and [two](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Transaction) usefull links to documentation.

But in your example, you provide one transaction for each `row`. When one of transaction fails, current row will not be saved and your code will generate new transaction for next row.

In this case, there is no benefit in performance from using `autocommit=False`.
If your dataset is large, you can try to to split it into separate chunks and use one transaction per chunk. Or use autocommit option and do not worry about the state of transactions.